# SSIS: Curious: why is the last parameter in FireInformation method a ref bool?

Tags: .net, ssis, class-design

I'm currently working on a SSIS package and after the 80th time using FireInformation inside a Script Task, I have to wonder: why would the method require you to pass in a ref boolean as its last parameter? The documentation doesn't state anything about how you should respond to the value once the method returns. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The run-time engine has the ability to modify the “fireAgain” parameter and prevent the further firing of events. In order to do this, the run-time must have access to modify the variable. It can only do this if the parameter is passed by ref.

Comment: You just resurrected a question from 4 years ago :P

Answer (score 1):

It is fireAgain parameter.

> Because firing of an event may be expensive, the run-time engine provides a mechanism for suppressing events that you are not interested in. Every event firing method has a FireAgain parameter. *If the value of this variable is false, after the method returns, the caller will not fire this event again for the duration of the current execution.*
>   [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtscomponentevents.fireinformation.aspx)

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the design choice to make it a ref parameter. Especially considering that since the caller was the one who called the method, then the caller already knows the value of the boolean parameter. It makes no sense to me.